# Extracting substring in linux using expr and regex

Tags: regex, linux, substring, expr

So I have just begun learning regular expressions. I have to extract a substring within a large string.

My string is basically one huge line containing a lot of stuff. I have identified the pattern based on which I need to extract. I need the number in this line `A lot of stuff<li>65,435 views</li>a lot of stuff` This number is just for example.

This entire string is in fact one big line and my file `views.txt` contains a lot of such lines.

So I tried this,

```
while read p
do
y=`expr "$p": ".*<li>\(.*\) views "`
echo $y
done < views.txt
```

I wished to iterate over all such lines within this `views.txt` file and print out the numbers.

And I get a syntax error. I really have no idea what is going wrong here. I believe that I have correctly flanked the number by `<li>` and `views` including the spaces.

My (limited) interpretation of the above regex leads me to believe that it would output the number.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which shell are you using?  bash? zsh? sh? tcsh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax error is because the ":" is not separated from "$p" by a space (or tab).  With that fixed, the regex has a trailing blank which will prevent it matching.  Fixing those two problems, your sample script works as intended.

Comment: 1.) Why do you need space to put : after $p
 2.) I thought that since there is a lot of stuff after views i need to put a space for the regex to match. So what is interpreted by that trailing space?

Comment: (1) the space is needed so that expr knows it is not part of the string, and (2) the trailing space would match a space after "views" -- but your example had none.